# How to determine the total pressure of a gaseous mixture of xenon tetrafluoride and hydrogen?

Tags: physical-chemistry, gas-laws

> Gaseous xenon tetrafluoride at partial pressure of $\pu{2 kPa}$ and hydrogen at partial pressure of $\pu{10 kPa}$, are exploded in an enclosed container producing xenon and hydrogen fluoride:
>   $$\ce{XeF4 (g) + 2 H2 (g) -> Xe (g) + 4 HF (g)}$$ 
>   Find out the total pressure of mixture of gases in the enclosed container.

Assuming $T$ and $V$ are constant, we can assume that the pressure is directly related to the amount of substance, hence $\pu{1 kPa}$ of $\ce{XeF4}$ reacts with $\pu{2 kPa}$ of $\ce{H2}$.

This means that only $\pu{4 kPa}$ of $\ce{H2}$ is needed to react with $\pu{2 kPa}$ of $\ce{XeF4}$.

Now, to find total pressure of mixture of gases I did

$$p = \pu{2 kPa}~\text{(from Xe)} + \pu{8 kPa}~\text{(from HF)} = \pu{10 kPa}$$

Why is this wrong? Why must I add $\pu{10 kPa}$ by $\pu{6 kPa}$ which is the unreacted hydrogen?

Comment: Pressure is an intensive property. An expression "$\pu{1 kPa}$ of $\ce{XeF4}$ reacts with $\pu{2 kPa}$ of $\ce{H2}$" makes no sense.

Comment: Please note that the proper term for "number of moles" is [amount of substance](http://goldbook.iupac.org/A00297.html). The former would be the same as referring to the mass as "number of kilograms".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are correct up to the last part. The total pressure would be the sum of all the partial pressures in the reaction vessel.

We know that $$P=\left(\frac{RT}{V}\right)n$$ and therefore $n$ varies directly with $P$ as $T$, $R$, and $V$ are constant. For the sake of the problem (it won't matter) we can just say that $x=\left(\frac{RT}{V}\right)$. Therefore, $P=xn$ and the starting amounts of substance are equal to $\frac{2}{x}\pu{ mol}$ $\ce{XeF4}$ and $\frac{10}{x}\pu{ mol}$ $\ce{H2}$.

From the balanced equation and the starting materials and stoichiometry, we know that $\frac{2}{x}\pu{ mol}$ $\ce{XeF4}$ would react with $\frac{4}{x}\pu{ mol}$ $\ce{H2}$ to form $\frac{2}{x}\pu{ mol}$ $\ce{Xe}$ and $\frac{8}{x}\pu{ mol}$  $\ce{HF}$ to make $\frac{10}{x}\pu{ mol}$ product.

However, you only reacted $\frac{4}{x}\pu{ mol}$ $\ce{H2}$ of the $\frac{10}{x}\pu{ mol}$ total, so there is $\frac{6}{x}\pu{ mol}$ unreacted $\ce{H2}$ left in the reaction vessel.

$$\begin{multline}
  \frac{10}{x}\text{ amount of substance of product } 
+ \frac{6}{x}\text{ amount of substance of unreacted }\\
= \frac{16}{x}\text{ total amount of substance}
\end{multline}$$

From $P=xn$, the fact that this occurred instantly, and $T$, $R$, and $V$ are constant, we then know that the final pressure is $\ce{16 kPa}$.

Comment: I would suggest to have a look at [How can I format math/chemistry expressions here?](https://chemistry.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/86/how-can-i-format-math-chemistry-expressions-here) regarding formatting guidelines. And again, pressure is an intensive property, one cannot say *that much* kPa reacts, it's like counting green and red apples by color.

Comment: Thank you for the link, I'm new here and didn't know where to look. In this case, because the reaction is happening in an explosion, and T and V are constant, the number of moles relates directly to the pressure by some constant $$P=(RT/V)n$$ For the sake of the problem, we can carry $RT/V$ through in our stoichiometry, then re-convert it out at the end. In the answer, I merely used this shortcut (which I should have made known) and did not say this.

Comment: I get that, but the *terminology* you and OP are using is just wrong, even though the answer seems to be correct. Comparing quantities using intensive parameters in this context makes little sense. That's all.

Comment: Please note that the proper term for "(number of) moles" is [amount of substance](http://goldbook.iupac.org/A00297.html). The former would be the same as referring to the mass as "number of kilograms".